# Simple relation between gradient and curl

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let us consider a function $u:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ smooth enough and decaying sufficiently fast as $\vert x\vert\to+\infty$. My question is, if we assume that $$
\hbox{for all } x\in\mathbb{R}^3,\quad \mathrm{div}(u)(x)=0, 
$$
does this implies that $$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \vert\nabla\times u(x)\vert^2dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\vert \nabla u(x)\vert^2dx?
$$
I tried to make some computations (trying to explicitly compute both sides of the equation) but I wasn't able to prove it. Of course, if it is true, I guess it is just a computation, but I don't see it.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention what means the notation. In the latter relation I am denoting by $\vert \nabla \times u\vert^2$ the quantity: $$
\vert \nabla \times u(x)\vert^2=(\nabla \times u)\cdot (\nabla \times u),
$$
and the same for $\vert \nabla u(x)\vert^2$.

Comment: How are you defining the Curl for $n>3$?  Anf what is the magnitude of the tensor $\nabla u$?

Comment: @MarkViola My bad, I don't know why I wrote $n$ instead of $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that$$\begin{align}|\nabla\times u|^2&=\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{ilm}\partial_ju_k\partial_lu_m\\&=(\delta_{jl}\delta_{km}-\delta_{jm}\delta_{kl})\partial_ju_k\partial_lu_m\\&=\partial_ju_k\partial_ju_k-\partial_ju_k\partial_ku_j\\&=(\nabla u)^2-\partial_ju_k\partial_ku_j,\end{align}$$so we want to check $\nabla\cdot u=0\implies\int_{\Bbb R^3}\partial_ju_k\partial_ku_jdx=0$. Integrating by parts,$$\int_{\Bbb R^3}\partial_ju_k\partial_ku_jdx=-\int_{\Bbb R^3}u_k\partial_k\underbrace{\partial_ju_j}_{0}dx=0.$$In particular, there's no boundary term provided $u_k\partial_ku_j$ vanishes at infinity.